# Hunt processes and its equivalence

Tags: stochastic-calculus, dirichlet-forms

I have a question about Hunt processes and its equivalence.

I'm reading *Dirichlet Forms and Symmetric Markov Processes* by M. Fukushima, Y. Oshima, and M. Takeda. The following theorem is stated in this book.

In the following, $X$ be a locally compact separable metric measure space and $m$ a Radon measure on $E$ with $\text{supp}[m]=E$.

> [Theorem 4.2.4] Let $\mathbb{M}_1$ and $\mathbb{M}_2$ be two
>   $m$-symmetric Hunt processes on $X$ possess a common regular Dirichlet
>   form on $L^{2}(X;m)$. Then, $\mathbb{M}_1$ and $\mathbb{M}_2$ are
>   equivalent. That is, there is a common properly exceptional set $N$
>   such that 
>   \begin{align*} p_{t}^{1}f(x)=p_{t}^{2}f(x),\quad x \in X
> \setminus N,\,t>0, 
> \end{align*} 
>   where $f$ is a bounded Borel measurable
>   function on $X$, $p_{t}^{i}$ is the transition function of
>   $\mathbb{M}_{i}$, $i=1,2$.

**Question**

Under what conditions does the following hold?

For any bounded Borel function $f$ and $t>0$, 
\begin{align*} 
(\ast)\quad p_{t}^{1}f(x)=p_{t}^{2}f(x),\quad x \in X ,\,t>0.
\end{align*}

There is a sufficient condition for $(\ast)$:

> [Proposition 4.1 in [this book](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0074090)]
>   Suppose that both $\mathbb{M}_1$ and $\mathbb{M}_2$ satisfy the absolute
>   continuity condition: for any $t>0$ and $x \in X$, 
>   \begin{align*}
> p_{t}^{1}(x,\cdot)\text{ and }p_{t}^{2}(x,\cdot)\text { are absolutely
> continuous w.r.t. }m.
> \end{align*} Then, $(\ast)$ holds.

The author says that this claim follows immediately from [Theorem 4.2.4], but I did not understand it... If you know, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder what Fukushima really meant, but the statement – as written – appears to be false: think of a diffiuson on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ for which $0$ is a non-exit entrance point on both sides, and extend this process to $\mathbb{R}$ in two ways, letting the process go either to the right or to the left when it starts at $0$.

To be specific, take the $2$-dimensional Bessel process: let $Y_t$ and $Z_t$ be independent standard Brownian motions, and define $X_t^{(1)} = ((x + Y_t)^2 + Z_t^2)^{1/2}$ if the starting point $X_0^{(1)} = x$ is positive and $X_t^{(1)} = -((x + Y_t)^2 + Z_t^2)^{1/2}$ if $x \leqslant 0$. Define $X_t^{(2)}$ in the same way, but change the conditions $x > 0$ and $x \leqslant 0$ to $x \geqslant 0$ and $x < 0$, respectively. Then $X_t^{(1)}$ and $X_t^{(2)}$ are equivalent in the sense of Dirichlet forms, satisfy the absolute continuity condition, but their laws are different when started at $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your example is a counter example for proposition 4.1.

Comment: Yes, that is right. (On the other hand, in order to prove some kind of uniqueness of the corresponding Markov process, one typically uses some kind of continuity of the heat kernel).

Comment: For example. if $\mathbb{M}_1$ has absolute continuity and $\mathbb{M}_2$ has strong feller property, we obtain the claim.

Comment: Indeed, for any bounded continuous function $f$ and $t>0$, we obtain $p_{s+t}^{1}f(x)=p_{s}^{1}(p_{t}^{2}f)(x)$ from absolute continuity of $\mathbb{M}_1$. Now, $f$ and $p_{t}^{2}f$ is continous from strong Feller property. Therefore, letting $s \to 0$, we obtain the claim from the sample path (right) continuity of $\mathbb{M}_1$.

Comment: What's the reference measure $m$ in this case?

Comment: For the example about the Bessel process it is $|x| dx$. The heat kernel is then $\mathbb{P}^x(X_t\in dy)=t^{-1}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/(2t)}I_0(xy/t)m(dy)$ when $xy>0$ and $0$ otherwise (here $I_0$ is the Bessel function). Thanks for pointing this out! (I have never worked with Dirichlet forms, though, so I would not be very surprised if it turns out that the two processes that I described above do not satisfy some condition).